# How to check if a numpy array is inside a Python sequence?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, sequence, membership

I'd like to check if a given array is inside a regular Python sequence (list, tuple, etc). For example, consider the following code:

```
import numpy as np

xs = np.array([1, 2, 3])
ys = np.array([4, 5, 6])

myseq = (xs, 1, True, ys, 'hello')
```

I would expect that simple membership checking with `in` would work, e.g.:

```
>>> xs in myseq
True
```

But apparently it fails if the element I'm trying to find isn't at the first position of `myseq`, e.g.:

```
>>> ys in myseq
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

So how can I perform this check?

If possible I'd like to do this without having to cast `myseq` into a numpy array or any other sort of data structure.

Comment: Do you only want to check if the array is in `myseq` and nothing else? Since you don't want to cast `myseq` into a numpy array or any other sort of data structure, would it be ok to use a helping data structure that is of a different type?

Comment: @mapf for some added context: I'm performing unit-tests in which I mock a function using `unittest.mock.MagicMock`. At one point, I want to see if a given array was used as a positional argument to the mocked function, so I get the call arguments with `called_args = MagicMock.call_args[0]` (a tuple) and check if the array is among the called args with `self.assertIn(array, called_args)`. But the test fails due to the behavior I described above. I'd prefer not have to touch the `called_args` tuple in the test because it feels hacky, but that's also ok if there are no better alternatives.

Comment: `any(e is ys for e in myseq)`

Comment: @dawg while this does work in my particular use case, it would introduce an issue if the array being tested is a copy of the array inside the sequence.

Comment: Then `any(isinstance(e, tp) and np.array_equal(e, arr) for e in seq)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `any` with the test that is appropriate:

```
import numpy as np

xs = np.array([1, 2, 3])
ys = np.array([4, 5, 6])
zs = np.array([7, 8, 9])

myseq = (xs, 1, True, ys, 'hello')

def arr_in_seq(arr, seq):
    tp=type(arr)
    return any(isinstance(e, tp) and np.array_equiv(e, arr) for e in seq)
```

Testing:

```
for x in (xs,ys,zs):
    print(arr_in_seq(x,myseq))
True
True
False
```

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not the most beatiful or fasted solution, but I think it works:

```
import numpy as np


def array_in_tuple(array, tpl):
    i = 0
    while i < len(tpl):
        if isinstance(tpl[i], np.ndarray) and np.array_equal(array, tpl[i]):
            return True
        i += 1
    return False


xs = np.array([1, 2, 3])
ys = np.array([4, 5, 6])

myseq = (xs, 1, True, ys, 'hello')


print(array_in_tuple(xs, myseq), array_in_tuple(ys, myseq), array_in_tuple(np.array([7, 8, 9]), myseq))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'll leave the question open for a bit just in case someone else has a simpler way of doing what I want, but this does answer my question and I'll be using it in my code.